# HttpUrlConnection and setReadTimeout() method

Tags: java, sockets, http, tcp, httpurlconnection

I want to know when and why the "java.net.SocketTimeoutException readtime out" is raised.

```
    URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        con.setReadTimeout(421);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        InputStream is =    con.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("Inputstream done");

        FileOutputStream fos = fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\tryfile\\file1.csv");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];              //declare 4KB buffer
            int len;

            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

          fos.close();
          is.close();
```

Here is the question.I set read timeout value 421 and I take "java.net.SocketTimeoutException readtime out" exception at that line 55.

```
while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
```

So I take the inputstream succesfuly but when I start reading/writing it I take this exception.And I check that the 732 Kb of the file is transfered until the exception.

So I really confused about it.Please explain readtimeout method exactly.

Comment: Is there something not clear in the [documentation of `setReadTimeout(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout%28int%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is raised when no data arrives between the inception of the `read()` call and the expiration of the specified timeout starting at that point. In other words, no data arrived within the timeout period.

> So I take the inputstream succesfully

Not surprising. It takes zero time and does nothing on the network, as you have already called `getResponseCode()` (and done nothing with it).

> but when I start reading/writing it I take this exception.

So the data was slow arriving.

> And I check that the 732 Kb of the file is transfered until the exception.

So the *end* of the data was slow arriving.

NB 421ms is far too short for a read timeout. It should be tens of seconds.

Comment: When I set readtimeout 3000 ms I can download 40 Mb zip file succesfuly.(I download it in two minutes without time out).So I understand that for every read method call(in while) it can be read timeout.I understand that for example, read time out value is the time that between second and third call of the read method(in while).Or between third and four,four and five.For every call in while it starts new specified timeout.Is that true ?

Comment: No. A read timeout can happen *inside* any of those `read()` calls. It's not a matter of 'between' them. It doesn't care how long you took *between* read() calls. It cares when you entered one, and whether data arrived *within the timeout starting from then*. You could sleep for a thousand years between read() calls without causing a read timeout, if the peer kept the connection alive that long.

Comment: But the program reads the first 4096 kb from inputstream with first call of the read method.And it starts writing it to the file.So while the program writing the first 4096 kb it took read timeout exception.İt writes 732 kb and while continuening to write first 4096 kb  it take exception.So it can happen between the read calls(while writing) or it can happen while reading the data from inputstream.Is that true?

Comment: I've already answered that. Twice. It happens *within* the read() calls, not *between* them. I can't make head or tail of your mutually contradictory statements about reading the first 4096 bytes, timing out on the first 4096 bytes, and writing the entire 732kb.